# Laravel many to many relationship with pivot table

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, pivot, pivot-table

if I try the following the page is loading endless:

```
$user_departments = User::find(1)->departments();
```

There are the following tables:
- users
- user_department
- departments

The pivot table user_department has got this two foreign keys:
- department_id
- user_id

In my user model:

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Department', 'user_department', 'user_id', 'department_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

In my department model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_department', 'department_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

By the way: The following code is working:

```
$user->departments()->syncWithoutDetaching($department->id);
```

But I can't get the departments of the user without breaking my page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Table/Field names are case sensitive, check your case.

Comment: Oh it was a mistake in my description. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When fetching the departments of a user. You should actually `get()` the results. With `$user->departments()` you are getting the query builder which isn't a collection of results.

Alternatively of using the `get()` method (`$user->departments()->get()`) You could use a shortcut: `$user->departments`.

Answer (score 0):

Use below syntax to get user departments :

```
$user->departments;
```

to insert :

```
$user->departments()->attach($department->id);
```

to remove :

```
$user->departments()->detach($department->id);
```

and for sync :

```
$arr=array(13,25,12);
$user->departments()->sync($arr);
```